# Strictly increasing seq in $[0,1]$ starts at $0$, ends at $1$ with interval between successive points contained in element of cover of $[0,1]$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Precisely, the question is:

Let $U$ be an open cover of $[0, 1]$ in the usual topology. Show that there are points $0 = s_{0} < ..< s_{n} = 1$ such that $\forall i < n$ we have $[s_{i}, s_{i+1}]\subset U_{i}$ for some $U_{i} \in U$.

My thought for solving this is to consider we can reduce $U$ to a finite subcover $U_{1}, ...U_{k}$ as $[0,1]$ is compact. For $s_{0}=0$, we can find $i \in \{1,...k\}$ such that $s_{0} \in U_{i}$. Likewise, $s_{n}=1 \in U_{j}$ for some $j \in \{1,...k\}$.

Now I am stuck on building the sequence. Of course, by openness of $U_{i}$, I can find $s_{0}<s_{1}$ such that $[s_{0}, s_{1}] \subset U_{i}$. But the problem is that $s_{1}$ might be "too small", leaving too much of $[0,1]$ to be covered by rest of sequence. Any suggestions?

Comment: Call $a\in [0,1]$  the supremum of the numbers such that $[0,a]$ satisfies the same property that you are trying to prove for $[0,1]$. Note that you already proved that $a>0$. Assume that $a<1$ and use some open $U_i$ in the collection that contains $a$ to reach a contradiction by proving that there is some $b>a$ such that $[0,b]$ also satisfies the same property.

Answer (score 1):

Lebesgue's number lemma gives you a number $\delta > 0$ such that any subset $S \subset [0, 1]$ of diameter less than $\delta$ is contained in some element of $U$. Choose $n>\frac{1}{\delta}$ and take $s_i=\frac{i}{n}$.